# iOS Web-App: Flicker between page transition

Tags: javascript, css, ios, twitter-bootstrap, flicker

I made a web app for iOS-Devices and used Bootstrap from Twitter, because it supports responsive design. The header and the footer sould behave like in a native app: fixed to the top or bottom. I achieved it using the CSS-class `.navbar-fixed-top` and `.navbar-fixed-bottom`.

Unfortunately, during the transition between two pages the header and footer flicker and it don't seem "natural". The bars sould be static.

I prepared a sample-website. I use exactly this structure.
http://goo.gl/lmvzJ

Do you know a trick or a better soulution? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I made a sample-website: [link](http://goo.gl/lmvzJ)

Comment: This is a difficult question. I see flickering in the navbar even on Twitter's github site (on the iPad).

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to do something like that, I'd go ahead and use Sencha touch to build the app. It costs money but it's awesome for building a web UI. You could also try jquery mobile.